# Disambiguate ambiguous reference to overloaded definiton

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do the following :

```
case class Params(param1: Int, param2: String)

class EntityCreator {
  def create(param1:  Int, param2: String): Int = {
    ...
  }

  def create(params: Params): Int = 
    // extract a tuple from params and pass it to create
    create _ tupled Params.unapply(params).get 
}
```

It gives the following compilation error:

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method create in class EntityCreator of type (params: Params)Int
and  method create in class EntityCreator of type (param1: Int, param2: String)Int
match expected type ?

       create _ tupled Params.unapply(params).get
```

Is there a way to tell the Scala compiler which of the two create functions I am referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `create _`, the compiler cannot decide which create function to use, because both of them are valid in this case.
You have to explicity specify the type information like this

`((param1:  Int, param2: String) => create(param1, param2)) tupled Params.unapply(params).get`

At which point you could just use
`def create(params: Params): Int = 
  create(params.param1, params.param2)`

Comment: Or `def f(p: Params) = p match { case Params(a,b) => f(a,b) }`

Comment: Also, `object EC { def f(x: Int, y: String): String = y * x ; def f(p: Params): String = (f(_:Int,_:String)) tupled Params.unapply(p).get }`